# Timeout detection for eventlisteners in Android

Tags: java, android, timeout

I set up event listener, for example: `setOnClickListener` like this

```
    Button stopBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    stopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doMagic();
        }
    });
```

I would like to set this listener a timeout event on 10s if button is not pressed. Use case: i have `button1` that activates this `stopBtn` listener for 10s and if timeout comes it becomes deactivated and i need to press `button1` to make `stopBtn` active again.

Im probably doing it wrong:

```
    final Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    startBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
    myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"runned");
                }
            });
        }
    }, 10000);
```

After 10s im still able to click it and that is probably cos event listener is still attached. How can i detach it even if i don't know if its fired or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [delayed Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) posted on a Handler could manage that:

```
myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
   if(something happened) {
     // magic work
   } else {
     // turn off the event
   }
 }
, 10000);
```

You can init the [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) as an instance variable by using this code:

```
final Handler myHandler = new Handler();
```

Comment: You could change the listener to a new one (maybe an empty one or whatever you need)

Answer (score 1):

Delayed actions can be arranged by using a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). Specifically check the 2 methods: [postAtTime(Runnable, long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postAtTime%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) and [postDelayed(Runnable, long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29).

It is easy to create a `Handler`, just use its default constructor `Handler handler = new Handler()` within the `Activity.onCreate(Bundle state)`. Then wrap your desired action into a `Runnable` and pass to the handler.

Comment: Oh, while I was writting this `Tim Messerschmidt` has already posted almost the same advice. :)