# java - onclicklistener timeout?

Tags: java, android, timeout, onclicklistener

I have a button which moves and changes the imagebutton immediately on every press, and on every 5th press activates a command. Now I'm trying to get it to timeout if 5 seconds elapses and then have the button disappear. I have been trying with the Handler example ([Timeout detection for eventlisteners in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097208/timeout-detection-for-eventlisteners-in-android)) but can't figure out exactly where to put the code to get it to work?

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {
 imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
 imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    int i=0;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        i+=1;
        //Move position
        Random r = new Random();
        int buttonHeight;
        int buttonWidth;
        int xPos = r.nextInt(480);
        int yPos = r.nextInt(800);
        imageButton.setX(xPos);
        imageButton.setY(yPos);

        //Change image
        int[] imageIds = {
                R.drawable.pic1,
                R.drawable.pic2,
                R.drawable.pic3,
                R.drawable.pic4,
                R.drawable.pic5,
                R.drawable.pic6,
                R.drawable.pic7,
                R.drawable.pic8,
                R.drawable.pic9,
                R.drawable.pic10

        };
        int randomImageId = imageIds[r.nextInt(imageIds.length)];
        imageButton.setImageResource(randomImageId);
        if(i==5){
            Toast offMsg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "This is the fifth button press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            offMsg.show();
            int i=0;
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Timeout after what?

Comment: will you explain clearly when button is visible and when time starts and when times out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do Something like this.

```
final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
    // Replace with your logic.
    button.setOnClickListener(null);
  }
};

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override public void onClick(final View view) {
    //Removing 5 Seconds timer which will remove click listener.
    view.removeCallbacks(runnable);
  }
});

//Removed Click Listener after 5 Seconds.
button.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
```

Create a `Runnable` and add your logic in `run` method.
Whenever you want to start timer use `postDelayed(Runnable runnable, long delay)` function start timer. And, To remove time just call `removeCallbacks(Runnable runnable)` and pass the same runnable. this will remove timer.